# How to write named scope for sub queries in Active Record Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying get unique records from a table based on category column.This query gives those unique records which has been tested on MYSQL. But I wanna know how to write the same thing in Rails as named scope.
Can anyone let me know how to write scope for the following query in Rails 5 application:

```
SELECT * FROM t where id = (select min(id) from t t2 where t2.category = t.category);
```

Comment: Could you explain further what this query does?

Comment: I am trying to get the first record for each category value.
id catgeory description
Table data:
1    abc      test
2    abc      test1
3    abc      test2
4    xyz      test
5    xyz       testabc
This query returns record 1 and record 4

Comment: have you tried reading https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope. What issue you faced while converting the query to scope, mention your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same implementation, hope you can get help.

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_details
end
```

category_detail.rb

```
class CategoryDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
   scope :get_first_category_vise_details, -> {order(:category_id).group_by(&:category_id).map{|cat_detail_group| cat_detail_group.last.first} }
end

select * from categories;

+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | abc  |
|  2 | xyz  |
+----+------+

select * from category_details;

+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | category_id | description |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |           1 | test        |
|  2 |           1 | test1       |
|  3 |           1 | test2       |
|  4 |           2 | test        |
|  5 |           2 | testabc     |
+----+-------------+-------------+

CategoryDetail.get_first_category_vise_details

[#<CategoryDetail id: 1, category_id: 1, description: "test">, #<CategoryDetail id: 4, category_id: 2, description: "test">]
```

Comment: class Discrepancy < ApplicationRecord

  scope :get_first_category_vise_details, -> {order(:category).group_by(&:category).map{|cat_detail_group| cat_detail_group.last.first.id} }
end
Discrepancy.get_first_category_vise_details  gives me "NoMethodError (undefined method `get_first_category_vise_details' for #<Class:0x0000000009227370>)"

Comment: I am getting "NoMethodError (undefined method `get_first_category_vise_details' for #<Class:0x0000000009227370>)" error

Comment: Have you define the scope "get_first_category_vise_details" in model  Discrepancy? What is the result of Discrepancy.respond_to?(:get_first_category_vise_details)

Comment: Its working ! Thanks . BTW i got the above error if i run Discrepancy.get_first_category_vise_details on rails console. It worked fine when I used it select statement